# Get-AzSqlDatabase doesn't retrieve all the databases

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-runbook

I'm writing a runbook in powershell for azure where I want to retrieve all the databases from my server, where I have 1000+ databases, but when I execute the command Get-AzSqlDatabase it just returns 100 databases, instead of what I was expecting, which is all my databases. Is there a limit and any way to avoid it?

This is my code:

```
$Subscription = Get-AzSubscription 

if($Subscription){

    $AzSqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer 

    if($AzSqlServer)
    {
        Foreach ($server in $AzSqlServer){
            $SQLDatabase=Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName  $server.ResourceGroupName 
"Count:"+$SQLDatabase.Count
}
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't now the commands which you use but, your are overwriting  your `$SQLDatabase` for each server. So in the end you will only have the DBs of your last server in `$AzSqlServer`. Use `$SQLDatabase +=` instead. Or better find out how to use a collection in powershell and define your collection outside of the foreach loop and add the object inside of your loop

Comment: Oh, right now I'm just printing the number to check, but later on I'll loop the databases and do more work with them, this was just a test!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @guiwhatstha, you are overwriting the variable `$SQLDatabase` within the for loop to capture all the results, you could assign the result of the for loop to the variable `$SQLDatabase` as follow:

```
$Subscription = Get-AzSubscription 
if($Subscription){
    $AzSqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer
    if($AzSqlServer)
    {
        $SQLDatabase= Foreach ($server in $AzSqlServer){
        Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName  $server.ResourceGroupName 
        }
     write-output "Count: $($SQLDatabase.count)"
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't exactly solve the issue, I still get 100 databases for every server

Comment: Did you try this script from windows powershell or azure powershell?

Comment: Please check this link https://ddeevv.com/question/get-azsqldatabase-only-returns-100-databases-qa6e20.html, you may need to translate the page to English

Comment: you are welcome 